# set selected value in angular5 ng-select programmaticaly

Tags: angular5, selecteditem, selectedvalue, angular-ngselect

I'm using angular5 ng-select component:
https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select
and try to set the **selected value** (programatically) when the container component first loaded (kind of default selected value set in the model).
I didn't find any relevant attribute for it or for the **isSelected** for each item.
Here is my code (filtered):
HTML:

```
<ng-select [items]="filter.values"  bindLabel="text" bindValue="id" class="input-md" [(ngModel)]="filter.selectedValue"></ng-select>
```

Model:

```
export class FilterData
{
    Name : string;
    FormattedName : string;
    values : Filter[];
    selectedValue : Filter = null;
    constructor(filterData : FilterData)
    {
        this.Name = filterData.Name;
        this.values = filterData.values;
        this.selectedValue = typeof filterData.selectedValue == "undefined" ? null : filterData.selectedValue;
    }
}

export class Filter 
{
    public id: number;
    public text: string;
}
```

Comment: Might wanna try [Angular Material Select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just find the item

```js
    let item = this.ngSelect.itemsList.findByLabel('label of the item');
```

and then set it back

```js
    this.ngSelect.select(item);
```

you need a reference to ng-select in your angular component

```js
    @ViewChild(NgSelectComponent)
    ngSelect: NgSelectComponent;
```

Comment: ngselectcomponent is not defined

Comment: Above code is working for me. But now it is giving me error of Expression has changed as i am using it with Reactive form. .changeDetection method of angular core is also not working. Any idea ?