# How to insert values in Observable type of array in ng-select

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6, angular-ngselect

I am using [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) and specifically using typeahead to fetch the list from the server as user types. Following example as described in [typeahead example : `people3$`](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/demo/app/examples/search.component.ts). My requirement is to add value when user clicks a button (I have `id` and `label` and corresponding object) but I am failing to understand :

1. How can I push Item to `item : Observable<any[]>` I tried doing `this.item = concat(of([{label:this.field.display,id:value}]))` it pushes the value but it does not reflect the value in ng-select until I click somewhere else outside the element.
2. I tried [this solution by `@ViewChild`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168270/set-selected-value-in-angular5-ng-select) and on `this.ngSelect.items = [{label:this.field.display,id:value}]` still it does not show value in ng-select.

[image: error]

After adding value in group, I have added the object but still it does not shows, If i click anywhere soon value will be shown.

I want to know

1. What possibly can be the reason for this behaviour.
2. preferred way to push items in `Observable<any[]>`

Here is my ng-select configuration :

```
<ng-select class="form-control ng-select-padding"
                 [items]="referenceItems | async"
                 [hideSelected]="true"
                 [loading]="searchFailed"
                 [typeahead]="searchReferenceItems"
                 bindLabel="label"
                 bindValue="id"
                 (change)="setField($event)"
                 (blur)="onUpdated()"
                 [formControlName]="field.name" ngDefaultControl>
      </ng-select>

//@ TS file

searchReferenceItems =  new Subject<object>();
referenceItems: Observable<any[]> ;
```

Thanks for your kind help

Comment: is there any error in your console?

Comment: No, there is no error as such

Comment: "it pushes the value but it does not reflect the value in ng-select until I click somewhere else outside the element."  The observable *ISN'T* the value.  Think of it as a "placeholder" to let you know "when something happens".  "Nothing changes" until "something happens"!  Q: Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The observable must be notified by the next function you can use a BehaviorSubject and the function asObservable() to show the elements.

```
   subject = new BehaviourSubject<any>([]) 
   referenceItems = this.subject.asObservable();
```

Then when ever you want to update the value you can use the 'next' function to the subject.

```
   this.subject.next(this.subject.value.concat({id:..., label:...}));
```

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: Hi,
Yeah I tried it but no luck
will try and share stackblitz example for same

Comment: Ok, share the stackblitz

Comment: @AbelValdez there's a mispelling error: "BehaviorSubject" not "BehaviourSubject"